# Blank white space at the top of screen

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I am getting a white space above my image.
Here is the CSS part that I'm having trouble with:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button_container {
  max-width: 50%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
}

.button .button_highlight a:hover {
  color: #60737c;
}

.button_highlight {
  background: rgba(253, 80, 76, 1.0);
}

.button_wrapper a:hover {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cf:after,
.cf:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

#main {
  background-image: url('.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#h1_blank {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#h1_main {
  margin-top: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#main p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#h3_1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3rem 0;
}

#services .service_p {
  color: #414141;
  margin: 0;
}

#services .service_p2 {
  color: #777777;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#services {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#services .service {
  background: #ffffff;
  float: none;
  padding: 3rem 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  /*
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      */
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

#services .service_2 {
  background: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  padding: 3rem 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  /*
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
      */
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#headline_section {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(253, 80, 76, 1.0);
  color: #fff;
}

#services h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #414141;
}

#services .button {
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
}

#clients .client_p {
  color: #414141;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#clients {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 6.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

#clients .client {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding: 6rem 2.5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 57px 0px rgba(4, 6, 9, 0.25);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

#clients .button {
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
}

#h3_cli {
  text-align: center;
  color: #414141;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#clients .source {
  color: #606060;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}

footer {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(253, 80, 76, 1.0);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer_h4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="main">
  <h1 id="h1_blank"></h1>
  <h1 id="h1_main">Offical Site</h1>
  <p>Official home page of  <br> Explore the group's social media, merch, and more!</p>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a href="socialmedia.html" class="button button_highlight">Social Media</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a href="merch.html" class="button button_highlight">Merch</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="button button_highlight" onclick="alert('This action is not yet supported on this site')">About Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="services" class="cf">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h2 id="headline_section">About Us</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="service">
          <img src=".jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
          <h3></h3>
          <p class="service_p">Test</p>
          <p class="service_p2"><i>Test</i></p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">

          <div class="service">
            <img src=".jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
            <h3></h3>
            <p class="service_p">Test</p>
            <p class="service_p2"><i>Test</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

          <div class="service">
            <img src=".jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
            <h3></h3>
            <p class="service_p">Test</p>
            <p class="service_p2"><i>Test</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>


<section id="clients" class="cf">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="client">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p class="client_p">Test</p>


    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</body>
<footer>

  <h4 id="footer_h4">Copyright &copy; 2018</h4>


</footer>
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Comment: `body{margin:0}`

Comment: Try css body{margin:0px}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this...

```
#h1_main {
  margin-top: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is my body: body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Comment: can you revise your question with full html and css so that we can see if something else is contradicting your ideal solution

Comment: Not sure how to insert code through comment. New to this site lol. Can you help?

Comment: Go back up to your question and click "edit" to revise your question with rest of code

Comment: to put code in a comment, you type ` (next to #1 on keyboard) and then put code and then type that character again.

Comment: is there an easier way then to space every line 4 times?

Comment: highlight the code and hit the { } in the editor tools.  That automatically formats it for you

Comment: thank you so much. Added Lorem ipsum because I had too much code compared to text.